# Odoo 10 Website_hr_recruitment

Tags: odoo-10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8okU.png)

```
   Hello for all , I have a form and i wish that the field "Nombre d'années d'expérience" will be added in the model of hr.applicant
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vD5g.png)

```
    In the case 
    { nom : Koussay
    Prénom Abdouli 
    Email : ...
    works correctly , but the hole problem is on the field 
    "Nombre d'années d'expérience" }
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to inherit the recruitment template id " apply "to display your fields

```
<template id="show_year_number"
            inherit_id="website_hr_recruitment.apply" name="Show year number">
            <xpath expr="//div/div/div[3]"
                position="after">
                <div class="form-group row form-field o_website_form_required_custom">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 text-right">
                                <label class="col-form-label" for="number_year_experience">Your File name</label> <!-- add your field name nembre anne... -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control o_website_form_input" name="your_field_name_here" required=""/> <!-- add your field name nembre anne... -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </xpath>
</template>


<function model="ir.model.fields" name="formbuilder_whitelist">
            <value>hr.applicant</value>
            <value eval="[
                'description',
                'email_from',
                'partner_name',
                'partner_phone',
                'job_id',
                'department_id',
                'your_field_name_here',  <!-- add your field name nembre anne... -->
            ]"/>
        </function>
```